# Hang over a minute on every click of a folder in Windows 10 File Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer

I just got a new Asus laptop with Windows 10 Pro build 18363.  I removed McAfee and Cortana, and disabled Cortana with a registry setting at `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search` (Name AllowCortana, Value DWORD 1).  Otherwise the Asus software seems okay.  I might try to decrapify it a little further, but didn't want to go all-out yet.

Now when I do anything in Windows File Explorer, I get a one- to two-minute hang just left-clicking on folders.  Explorer opens to "This PC", I double-click on C:\ and that opens immediately, but then I **click** on Program Files or any folder and I get the hourglass pointer while I wait **over a minute**, then the folder appears selected but I go right back to the hourglass pointer and a hang for over a minute, then the hourglass pointer goes back to an arrow and it works well again, except when I single-click on any folder, and I again get the hourglass pointer and a long hang. Can't switch tab or even move or resize the window.

The same hang happens when I single-click, double-click, or right click any folder or any quick link or "This PC" left-nav link.  Clicking, opening, or right-clicking on actual **files** has no problem, but all **folders** seem to give the same issue.

I wondered if disabling Cortana could be related, so I removed the above mentioned registry value to allow Cortana, but that did not help.

What else can I do to troubleshoot this?

EDIT: I timed the delay and it always seems to be 85 seconds.

EDIT: When I browse folders inside an app's standard "Open" dialog, I can use it all without problems--whether in the main file view, Quick access, or This PC.

Comment: Cortana can be turned off, but I think disabling it with a registry change (third party I think) may have caused this. Try reversing the registry change and then restart the computer.

Comment: I tried reverting the registry change, but it didn't help, as I mentioned above.  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I removed the above mentioned registry value to allow Cortana, but
> that did not help

Try two things:

(1) Make a new, test, Windows User Profile (Account). Log into the new Account and see if the error persists.

The issue could be Profile damage and if so, the only fix is to re-create the main User Profile (back it up, delete it, re-create it all from a different admin user account).

(2) Try the Windows first repairs.

> Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> dism.exe /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup
>
> dism.exe /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth
>
> SFC /SCANNOW

Restart and test.

If the above does not work, there is sufficient damage that you will be best to back up the system and re-install Windows fresh.

Comment: When I try to create a user, I click "I don't have this person's sign-in information" (rather than inputting an email), then I immediately get "Something went wrong/Try again, or select Cancel to set up your device later."  So that's messed up, too.

I'm trying part (2) now.

Comment: Running DISM and SFC did not help.  Thanks for trying!

Comment: At the end of my answer I posted that because the damage was extensive (from what I can see and repairs did not help) that you should back up and install Windows again. Since the computer is new, that should not be too bad to do.

Comment: Didn't need to do a full reinstall, but just used the Recovery "Reset this PC" feature, which seems like a partial reinstall.  That fixed it. Just wish I knew what caused it in the first place, lest I am likely to do it again!

Answer (score 0):

You are unable apparently to completely undo the changes you did to
your computer.

I suggest to use System Restore to rollback Windows to before this was done.
See the article
[How to Do a System Restore of Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4588-system-restore-windows-10-a.html).

Just to remark that disabling Cortana is possible without doubtful registry changes.
Just right-click Cortana on the taskbar and choose to hide it.

Comment: System restore back to the earliest restore point (a week ago) did not help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue *might* be that your PC is trying to sync to OneDrive when clicking on folders, and if the Internet is not available, it's timing out. Two things to try:

- [Disable OneDrive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-off-disable-or-uninstall-onedrive-f32a17ce-3336-40fe-9c38-6efb09f944b0). That might fix the *immediate* problem.
- [Modify the installation to use local credentials](https://www.howtogeek.com/451396/how-to-switch-to-a-local-user-account-on-windows-10/) rather than logging into Microsoft. If you do not need to synchronize across the web, this avoids that network traffic.

Comment: I am already on local credentials, and my internet connection is working very well. Disabling OneDrive did not help.  I'm going to try uninstalling OneDrive.

Comment: Uninstalling OneDrive did not help.